# Enter key triggers jquery .on function for different field

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the enter key is used on the input type=text field, the defined jquery .on function is triggered for the input type=image field within the table. Both those fields are within the same form, however they don't use the same class. Is there a way to prevent the enter key from triggering on the input type=image's functionality when it is used within the input type=text field?

Basically I want it to be like:

- enter key pressed on input type=image --> call .on function
- enter key pressed on input type=text  --> do default behaviour (dont't call the .on function)

Also, I noticed that when the enter key is pressed within the input type=text field, the "click" event is automatically used rather than a "keydown" or "keypress" event. Is this natural behavior?

**jquery**

```
$('#items tbody').on('keypress click', '.cssWrapper', function)
```

**html**

```
<table id="items">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>East</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>Open</td>
            <td>
                <div class="cssWrapper">
                    <input type="image" src="item.jpg" id="img_1">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>West</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>Close</td>
            <td>
                <div class="cssWrapper">
                    <input type="image" src="item.jpg" id="img_2">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="addr">Address - </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="addr" name="addr" type="text" maxlength="30" title="Enter Address">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're not targeting the input, but the parent div, which has no keypress event, just a click event, that fires whenever you click something inside that element.

Comment: Also, see [this](/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter).  It's got relevant info on handling enter.

Comment: @adeneo: Can you give some example code based on what you mentioned?